# Centering a div on screen even when the page is scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css

There has to be a easy solution to this. I have been trying to work with jQuery to accomplish the effect i am looking for but, it just isn't quite working... Also i suspect there is a CSS solution to the problem.

I have a div called "popup" with the following CSS:

```
#popup {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
bottom: 0px;}
```

It covers the screen like a overlay... Inside this div i have another called #pnlEditOverlay that is a box that has a notification message or a edit form or something similar.

**pnlEditOverlay is what i am trying to center vertically on the page**

I use jQuery to expand the height of #popup to the document height, so that it covers everything:

```
$("#popup").css('height', $(document).height());
```

My issue is that i would like to vertically center #pnlEditOverlay on the page even if the page is large enough where it can be scrolled.

I have been using jQuery to reposition this div:

```
var offset = $("#pnlEditOverlay").offset();

        var topPadding = 75;
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $("#pnlEditOverlay").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $("#pnlEditOverlay").stop().animate({
                    marginTop: 75
                });
            };
        }).scroll();
```

**However this is not exactly what i want.** It only repositions when the page is scrolled... So when the user is already scrolled halfway down the page, the div is hidden until they scroll...

In any case. I was wondering if there is a elegant CSS solutions to this. **I simple want to put a box dead center on the page, even if the page is scrolled.** I'm OK with using jQuery to set the styles of the div, however i **would like to avoid implement a click event** as there are MANY MANY buttons that could cause the div to be shown.

So the questions is, is there a CSS style or a small piece of jQuery that will center a div vertically and keep it there even if the page is scrolled?

Thanks

Comment: Consult all related questions stack overflow shows you as you are typing your question (you can find these on the right side of this page now). There's always a good chance you'll find your answer in one of them. Especially true for this question which is a common query with designers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a simple CSS solution for this. Firstly, use this for `popup`:

```
#popup
{
position:fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

and this for your `overlay`:

```
#overlay
{
position:fixed;
top:50%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-y;
margin-left:-x;
}
```

where *x* and *y* are **half** the width and height of your `overlay` div respectively. So you'd need to know the height and width of this div.

This will take care of all your problems, even when the page will be scrolled.

Comment: I know the width, but they height of #overlay is variable. Any ideas on how to work around this?

Comment: Actually that is not so important as i have a fixed margin from the top... This will work, thank you!

Comment: One edit i would make to this is to set the position of #popup. If you have margins on the div in your content, the #popup div may position incorrectly... left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

You need to account for the window's initial scroll offset when you open the popup. Instead of leaving it with a top position of absolute 0, you need to use Javascript to reposition it to the current value of the window's topmost visible pixel. I believe this is the offsetHeight parameter but I haven't tested.

Also FWIW, isn't there a "modal dialog" option in Jquery which does what you're expecting, out of the box? Did that not work for some reason?