# Showing a hidden div and centering on screen

Tags: javascript

**Update**

I've just updated the jsFiddle so that you can see the "pop up" happening and how it's never centered. It's always 200px from top.

So if the user has scrolled down a long page and clicked to make the pop up happen, the pop up is back up at the top of the page - 200px instead of centered on the visible screen.

http://jsfiddle.net/JYgcj/40/

I'll try out the answer below and update with results of that

---

I have a hidden div included in my layout as a partial

Here is the partial

A javascript function shows this div for showing the result of ajax requests

```
function showResultPopUpDiv(divId, title) {

    var popUpId = document.getElementById(divId);
    var popUpHeader = title;
    var originalDivHTML;
    var topPos = 200;
    var popUpWidth;
    var midPos;
    var leftPos;
    var spinnerOpts;

    //Insert header text & open pop up
    popUpId.style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("ajaxResultPopUpHeaderText").innerHTML = popUpHeader;

    //Set position dimensions
    popUpWidth = popUpId.offsetWidth / 2;
    midPos = $(document).width() / 2;
    leftPos = midPos - popUpWidth;

    //Position pop up (center)
    popUpId.style.top = topPos + "px";
    popUpId.style.left = leftPos + "px";

    //Insert spinning loader code here
    ... //left out for brevity
}
```

If a view is longer than a single screen and the user has scrolled to the bottom and clicked the submit button, this div pops up but cannot be seen unless the user scrolls back to the top.

How do I get this to center on the window correctly wherever the page is currently scrolled to.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447180/centering-a-div-on-screen-even-when-the-page-is-scrollable) and others that I've investigated have not solved this for me. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a live demo we can see?

Comment: Sorry, no it's an internal application. I could probably whip up a jsFiddle tho :-) But it would simply show the div, getting a jsFiddle screen to scroll longer than it is tho would be a problem

Comment: Looking at your jsFiddle page, is there a particular reason for having matching IDs and classes? You're using the ID in places for jQuery, but using a class in the CSS.

Comment: Yes, the id is used for other scripts that have nothing to do with styling. I stripped the extraneous code from the scripts dealing with those

Comment: I didn't write the code, just helping the UI guy get caught up so my task it to fix the centering issue. He has other scripts that use the ID.

Comment: But IDs can be used for styling. Having the same (long) class name *and* ID on each element is unnecessary, unless the class is going to be re-used (at which point it is confusing for it to have the same name as the ID, which can only occur once by definition).

Comment: Again, not my code, the UI guy has this for a reason. The question is to center the div wherever the page is scrolled to so that's my only task here. I'll bring up the duplicitous naming to him and verify his direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a CSS position of "Fixed" ([CSS Positioning 101](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/)). This will keep the object fixed relative to the viewport (the browser) rather than relative to the document. This will affect the way top and left behave.

Make sure you have something like:

```
#ajaxResultPopUpHeaderText {
    position: fixed; /* Make the position fixed to the viewport,
    so it stays in the same place no matter how much the user scrolls */
}
```

To centre on the viewport you need to calculate positions relative to the viewport. The [full JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PLhGu/7/) (forked from your original, with added content for scrolling and styling to keep the button with you as you scroll) has all of the JavaScript, but since you're working with jQuery then you just need to use `$(window)` instead of `$(document)`.

```
    //Set position dimensions
    var popUpHeight = popUpId.offsetHeight / 2;
    var centrePos = $(window).height() / 2;
    topPos = centrePos - popUpHeight;
    popUpWidth = popUpId.offsetWidth / 2;
    midPos = $(window).width() / 2;
    leftPos = midPos - popUpWidth;
```

`$(document)` happens to work okay for width, because the document is generally 100% of the width, but you should use `$(window)` anyway.

Comment: This CSS class is setting the width and height to the popup as a percentage. My div is a fixed width and height in my css (like a popup - it is always the same size) Screen sizes vary tho which would cause the div to look different on different browsers if using percentages, correct?

Comment: If you're using fixed width then you'll still need `position: fixed` to make its position fixed relative to the viewport (browser window) rather than relative to the page or another parent tag, but you might have to keep the JavaScript to calculate top/left/width/height.

Comment: I think the problem is this line 'var topPos = 200;' which forces it to always bee 200px from the top... not sure, this is me helping the UI guy out and trying to learn :-)

Comment: I've updated the example web page. It uses arbitrary pixel values in CSS, but has a top position of 200px and so will always be 200px from the top of the screen, wherever you scroll to. If you keep the `position: fixed` part that I suggested then the JavaScript should work the same as the CSS, since the JavaScript just edits an in-line `style` attribute, which is only CSS.

Comment: I appreciate the effort but that code doesn't give me what I need according to my req's. That example doesn't center the div. I'll keep plugging away at it too

Comment: I've updated the fiddle so the pop up is a result of a click. You can see how it's always 200px from top of page instead of centered on visible screen

Comment: @CDSmith - I was just using 200px as an example, since that was a number you'd quoted. I'll try to fork and update the JSFiddle.

Comment: The 200 is because the var topPos = 200 in the script. That feels wrong to me and part of the problem

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I assumed the 200px was intentional, that "centralised" was just referring to horizontal, and that your problem was only that the user had to scroll rather than seeing the div in the viewport after they'd scrolled. Glad it is fixed now.